# Window Management

Tags: javascript

I Need help in managing windows.

How to pass object from parent Window to Child Window.

`ChildWindow` is opened using `parentWindow.open()`.

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Have you tried researching this? You need to give a lot more information in your question. Is the child window on the same domain as the parent?

Comment: what...have...you...tried? <MorganFreemaninPulpFictionvoice>

Comment: I am using Javascript developing UI.I have a mainPage.html In MainPage, in <script> i am calling window.open("mainPage.html","new1") to open a new window. I Need to pass an object form <script> of main to new child window..

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable in your child windows, just as any other object:

```
var myValue = { foo: 'bar' };
var childWindow = window.open("URL_SAME_DOMAIN");
childWindow.Variable = myValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response..                                         But my problem is , after opening 2 windows(parent & child) ,which have same <script>.... i need to have some global variable which is global to both windows so that i can manage data from 1 window to other.

Comment: You can't have 'more' global than `window` itself, and since parent and child *is* both an instance of `window`, you need to manually set a variable on both of them to act as a global variable.